# transition: width Change direction

Tags: css

The default change of direction of CSS3 property `transition: width 1s` is to increase the width from left to right.

How is it possible to reverse the direction to right to left? Is it possible in CSS3? or some other jQuery plugin will be required?
please look at the [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sangramfuture/GS3VJ/12/). When you press button the width increases left to right. I want to reverse that.

Comment: You have to be more specific about your DOM etc. so we can help you

Comment: please find the `demo fiddle` attached. (just edited)

Comment: And how would you expect it to behave? Even if it was getting larger from the left, it is still a static element in a static place.

Comment: if you notice, the search box on SO on top, increases its width towards the left. I want the same thing. SO inspires me! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to put them inside a `right` aligned container.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/GS3VJ/13/)

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <input type='text'> </input>
    <button> increase width </button>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {    
    text-align: right;
    width: 450px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

See this example, I have applied css for both mozilla and webkit.

http://jsfiddle.net/2D7Ss/39/

```
-moz-transition: left 1s ease 0.1s, width 0s ease-out 0.1s, border-width 0s ease-out 0.1s;
-webkit-transition: left 1s ease 0.1s, width 0s ease-out 0.1s, border-width 0s ease-out 0.1s;
```